# paper.dvi --> paper.pdf, not working,how to fix?

Tags: xdvipdfmx

I am using Miktex2.9 on Windows 10. It was five days ago. Today I am suddenly having a problem.

I use "latex"  command from the menu, it is fine. but "DVI->PDF" is not working. and there is an error.

```
  Process started

  paper.dvi -> paper.pdf [1 xdvipdfmx:fatal: Could not find encoding file "8r". Output file removed.

 Process exited with error(s)
```

I have checked the internet, but did not see anyone having this error.
I remember previously I have a problem with "xdvipdfmx", but I fixed it and it has been working fine.

So, any advice how to fix that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: it probably doesn't matter but xdvipdfmx is normally only used with xetex and with latex you normally use  dvipdfmx

Comment: Did you run an update? Then you perhaps have problems with the november refactoring: http://www.miktex.org/alert/package-refactoring-2016-11

Comment: @UlrikeFischer. I run update, then running "latex" shows an error "! Package graphics Error: No driver specified." . what to do now?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer. You are right. followed your idea, do something after that, then it worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems  what  Ulrike Fischer said is right.  I updated MiKTeX then run "latex" had some problem. Then I go to MiKTeX setting and choose "ask me first"  for "install packages on the fly" option.

Then I run `latex` again. It asked to install 3-4 packages, then it worked.
Seems  November refactoring caused the original problem. Updating somehow deleted some packages, then after installing then Miktex worked fine.